# Laravel asset with sub domain

Tags: laravel

I need to make asset() work without writing subdomain name:

**My Code:**

```
asset('images/logos/logo-partner-5.png')
```

**Code which work but don't want:**

```
asset('subdomain/images/logos/logo-partner-5.png')
```

Any suggestion?

maybe to not use *asset()* but other function? exist another way?

or how to config the *asset()* path?

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:**

Laravel 5.7.14 will ship with an `asset_url` config option to do exactly this.

Original response below:

---

You can define your own helper function:

```php
function cdn_asset($path, $secure = null) {
    return app('url')->assetFrom(config('app.cdn_subdomain'), $path, $secure);
}
```

And place the config value in `config/app.php`:

```php
'cdn_subdomain' => 'http://subdomain.example.com',
```

Usage:

```php
<img src="{{ cdn_asset('images/logos/logo-partner-5.png') }}">
```

I named the function `cdn_asset()` because that seems like the most common situation for serving assets from a different domain, but you can call it whatever you like.

---

If you ***always*** want ***all*** assets served from the subdomain, you can override Laravel's asset helper. This might get a little dirty:

If you look in `Illuminate\Foundation\helpers.php`, you'll see that Laravel checks if the function exists before creating it:

```php
if (! function_exists('asset')) {
    function asset() { ... }
}
```

Which means you can define the function before Laravel does, and it will use yours instead:

```php
function asset($path, $secure = null) {
    return app('url')->assetFrom('http://subdomain.example.com', $path, $secure);
}
```

If you create a file called `/app/helpers.php` to define this function, you need to require it *before* Laravel loads the `/vendor/autoload.php` file. As of Laravel 5.7, this happens in `/public/index.php`. Add your own line before this happens:

```php
require __DIR__.'/../app/helpers.php'; // this is yours
require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';
```

You might also want to require it in the `artisan` file in the base path of the project.